# Debugging Python with GDB

Tags: python, debugging, gdb, breakpoints

Is it possible to debug python code as you would debug C++ code with `gdb`?
I found [this documentation](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Python.html#Python) but I cannot get my head around how to use it.
It would be cool to set breakpoints in my python script so that I can debug it in parallel with my C++ extension using [boost](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_78_0/libs/python/doc/html/faq/how_do_i_debug_my_python_extensi.html).

I'm using Ubuntu 20.04 with gdb version 9.2 and would like to debug python 3.6 code.

Comment: GDB will debug the interpreter, not the code.

Comment: pdb is standard in python. See: [https://docs.python.org/3/library/pdb.html](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pdb.html) if you would like. pdb can be launched from within the python code.